# How can I iterate through a CSS class' subclasses?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, css, ruby

I have a CSS file which contains several hundred 16x16 icons. They are referenced using a CSS class/subclass arrangement, like so:

```
<span class="icons icon_name"></span>
```

So, if I need an "arrow up" icon, I simply code:

```
<span class="icons arrow_up"></span>
```

And so on. Because there are so many icons in the library, I created a reference page (in [Haml](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Haml)), so I could quickly find which icon I need. An example of the Haml code:

```
%div.icons.arrow_turn_right
    arrow_turn_right
    %br
%div.icons.arrow_undo
    arrow_undo
    %br
%div.icons.arrow_up
    ss_arrow_up
    %br
```

It occurs to me that this is a rather brute force method to writing the page. 300 icons require nearly 1000 lines of code.

### My question: Is there a way to iterate through a CSS class' subclasses using an `each` loop (or something similar)?

Something like this:

```
subs = mainCSSclass.allSubclasses   <--Replace this line with functional code
subs.each do |subclass|
  ... display the |subclass| ...
end
```

Is such a thing possible?

Edit: Here is a partial of the actual CSS file being referenced:

```
.icons {
    display: inline;
    overflow: hidden;
    height: 16px;
    padding-left: 18px;
    background: url(icons.png) no-repeat; 
}

.accept {
    background-position: 0px 0px;
}

.add {
    background-position: 0px -19px; 
}

.anchor {
    background-position: 0px -37px;
}

.application {
    background-position: 0px -55px;
}

.application_add {
    background-position: 0px -73px; 
}

.application_cascade {
    background-position: 0px -91px; 
}
```

---

### Solution (thanks to @Corroded's answer):

In my pages_helper.rb:

```
def read_css_cfg
  css_classes = Array.new
  file = File.new("public/stylesheets/blueprint/plugins/icons/icons.css", "r")
    while line = file.gets
      parsed = line.scan(/[.]\w+ {/).to_s.scan(/\w/).join
      css_classes << parsed if !parsed.blank?
    end
    file.close
  css_classes
end
```

In my actual Haml file:

```
- parse = read_css_cfg
- parse.delete("icons")       #unrelated class, but in the same file'
- column = 1

.container
  - parse.each do |class_name|
    - case column
      - when 1
        <div class = "css_row">
        %div{:class => "icons #{class_name} three_column"}
          #{class_name}
        - column += 1
      - when 2
        %div{:class => "icons #{class_name} three_column"}
          #{class_name}
        - column += 1
      - when 3
        %div{:class => "icons #{class_name} three_column"}
          #{class_name}
        </div>
        - column = 1
```

Finally, though this has nothing to do with the original question, my final answer contained code which auto-generated a 3-column "div-table." If you're interested in the CSS to use DIV's instead of a table, here it is:

```
.container {
  display: table;
  width: 675px;
}

.three_column {
  display: table-cell;
  width: 225px;
}

.css_row {
  display: table-row;
```

Comment: You might want to look at SASS, which is rather popular in the Ruby/Rails community: http://sass-lang.com/

Comment: are you using silk icons? if so they already have a reference page for that www.famfamfam.com/lab/icons/silk/previews/index_abc.png(just assuming you are)

Comment: if you're not using silk, then can you post the a sample snippet of the css  to loop on?

Comment: I am using the silk icons, and am aware of their reference page, which is a simple enough solution. That said, I have a number of additional things I'd like to be doing with large CSS subset collections, which leads me back to wanting to know **how** to iterate thru a list of CSS subclasses. For one, I have heavily modified the original list, so the page isn't so relevant. Second, there is a lot of potential utility in knowing how to manipulate a large list like that (columns, search, reorganize, etc.)

Comment: please post a sample of the css file so we'll know how to loop through it

Comment: @corroded, I've added a sample of the actual CSS file to the original question.

Comment: Instead of hacking together some regexps, you could use an off the shelf css parser. There are many available, in addition to the Sass::CSS parser that @Michael already mentioned: http://tinyurl.com/3eg3dk9

Comment: Thanks, Tim. I'm having a hard look at SASS. I'm using it already, but it seems you're suggesting it's capable of much more than I was aware.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Okay, so basically, the plan is to loop through all those classes and generate them in a Haml page, right?

What I would do is open that CSS file (using Ruby of course) and then use a regular expression to parse and get all the subclasses. Since you would want to call that in a view, then I suggest using a helper:

```
def loadCSSClasses
    cssClasses = []
    cssFile = File.open("yourcssfile.css") do
        #Forgive me, my regular expression is weak, but basically you would want to get all the classnames after the word ".icon."
        cssClasses << className
    end
    cssClasses
end
```

Then in your Haml file do this:

```
%ul
  - loadCSSClasses.each do |class_name|
    %li{:class => "icon #{class_name}"
      = "ss_#{class_name}"
```

Comment: I see some definite possibility here. I hadn't thought of attacking it from this direction, but it looks like a potential solution. I stink at REGEX, too, so I tend to use http://www.rubular.com/ and cheat! I'll be back after I've tried out your solution.

Comment: good luck with the regex! i also use rubular.com but i still stink at it :P

Comment: Corroded's idea worked great. Final code is at the bottom of my original question.